# Using PCL with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, point-clouds, point-cloud-library

I am quite new at working with libraries, and  I have some problems.

I have installed PCL and all dependencies on my computer (Windows 7, 32 bit) and I can build and use simple examples like [that "Simple Cloud Visualization" example](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cloud_viewer.php#cloud-viewer). But if  I want to use [more complete sample](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cloud_viewer.php#cloud-viewer), Visual Studio 2010 reports linking errors.

If I understand correctly, I did not 'include' all necessary "Additional Dependencies" in "Linker/Input". I tried to include all .lib files from lib directory, but the error report is still the same.

Does anyone know, which .lib should be added as "Additional Dependencies" to make more complete sample work? Or is problem somewhere else?

error report:

> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkProperty * __thiscall vtkActor::GetProperty(void)" (?GetProperty@vtkActor@@QAEPAVvtkProperty@@XZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addSphere(struct pcl::PointXYZ const &,double,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,int)" (??$addSphere@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@PCLVisualizer@visualization@pcl@@QAE_NABUPointXYZ@2@NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z)
>   1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl pcl::console::print(enum pcl::console::VERBOSITY_LEVEL,char const *,...)" (?print@console@pcl@@YAXW4VERBOSITY_LEVEL@12@PBDZZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addSphere(struct pcl::PointXYZ const &,double,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,int)" (??$addSphere@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@PCLVisualizer@visualization@pcl@@QAE_NABUPointXYZ@2@NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z)
>   1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::~vtkSmartPointerBase(void)" (??1vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointer::~vtkSmartPointer(void)" (??1?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkLODActor@@@@QAE@XZ)
>   1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::vtkSmartPointerBase(void)" (??0vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointer::vtkSmartPointer(void)" (??0?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkLODActor@@@@QAE@XZ)
>   1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::vtkSmartPointerBase(class vtkSmartPointerBase const &)" (??0vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAE@ABV0@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointer::vtkSmartPointer(class vtkSmartPointer const &)" (??0?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkProp@@@@QAE@ABV0@@Z)
>   1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::vtkSmartPointerBase(class vtkObjectBase *)" (??0vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAE@PAVvtkObjectBase@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall vtkSmartPointer::vtkSmartPointer(class vtkSmartPointer const &)" (??$?0VvtkLODActor@@@?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkProp@@@@QAE@ABV?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkLODActor@@@@@Z)
>   1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class vtkSmartPointerBase & __thiscall vtkSmartPointerBase::operator=(class vtkObjectBase *)" (??4vtkSmartPointerBase@@QAEAAV0@PAVvtkObjectBase@@@Z) referenced in function "public: class vtkSmartPointer & __thiscall vtkSmartPointer::operator=(class vtkSmartPointer const &)" (??$?4VvtkLODActor@@@?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkProp@@@@QAEAAV0@ABV?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkLODActor@@@@@Z)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you installed the wrong PCL version (64 bit / 32 bit). Check your VS version and install PCL accordingly. Note that even if you are using a 64 bit system, your compiler may be working in 32 bit.